# ASP.NET MVC application : could not localize MessageFormat in ApplicationUserManager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider in IdentityConfig.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-identity

In a standard ASP.NET MVC (5.2.7) application with Identity (2.2.1) I'm trying to localize the message sent during the two factor authentication.

I have both `PhoneNumberTokenProvider` and `EmailTokenProvider`.

There is also a project with `*.resx` files containing the text messages in different languages.

In the application the current language is set based on custom language cookie.
And in every controller or view if I use `Resources.<<message_name>>` I get the text of the specific message for the `CurrentCulture` (`Resources` is the class name for the text resources project).

Now in `IdentityConfig.cs` I have:

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    ...
    // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
    // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
    manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = Resources.MESSAGE_PHONE
            });
```

This `ApplicationUserManager.Create` method is called on every request and so the `RegisterTwoFactorProvider`. The problem is that the `Resources.MESSAGE_PHONE` return always the message corresponding to the server locale - it does not change when another language is set on the page.

The `context` parameter has the right language cookie.

So the question would be why in `IdentityConfig\ApplicationManager.Create` method `Resource.MESSAGE_PHONE` does not return the message in the proper language (as in every controller or view). The project is relatively big and maybe there is some setting for the controllers and view, which I overlook ...

How could one solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite easy if you know where to look.

In my case the `CurrentCulture` is set in the `global.asax.cs` file in `Application_AcquireRequestState` and it is triggered after the `ApplicationUserManager.Create` method from the `IdentityConfig.cs` so in the `ApplicationUserManager.Create` the `CurrentThread` has only the default culture.

A solution would be to move the code setting the culture of the `CurrentThread` into the `Application_BeginRequest` method in the `global.asax.cs` which gets triggered before the `ApplicationUserManager.Create` method in the IdentityConfig.cs.

Full info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178473(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)